# NodeJs spawn giving ENOENT error (Raspbian)

Tags: node.js, child-process

i'm having an error regarding spawning nodeJs script:

```
exec('node ./modules/buttons', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if(error) console.log(error);
  console.log(stdout);
  if(stderr) console.log(stderr);
});
```

Exec Works perfectly fine. However *spawn*

```
var buttons = spawn('node ./modules/buttons.js', []);
buttons.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Gives me the following error:

```
spawn node ./modules/buttons.js ENOENT
```

Defining the absolute path to the script results in the same error. Would appreciate it if someone could help me resolving this; I have absolutely no clue what could be the cause of this and google isn't helping me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` accepts the command to be executed along with all the command line parameters, but spawn, OTOH, accepts the program to invoke and the command line arguments as an array.

In your case, Node.js is trying to execute a program called `node ./modules/buttons.js`, not `node` with `./modules/buttons.js` as command line argument. That is why it is failing.

Quoting the example from the [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) docs,

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

The difference between `exec` and `spawn` is that, `exec` will be default launch the command in a shell, `spawn` simply invokes the program.

**Note:** BTW, as you are simply invoking a JavaScript file, you are better off using [`execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

Comment: exec and execfile won't do what i want. I want to capture the stdout from the buttons.js script which runs a while true loop. Spawn should be able to help me out with that because of the message listener. Thanks for your answer though; Guess i didn't read the docs too well ;)

Comment: Did you try to do as per the example I quoted?

Comment: Yes it worked; thanks. However now im running into the issue that it only captures stdout of the spawned script for a brief period of time. After a while it just stops (the script keeps running though) It also seems to get cancelled out by the input of other spawned childs. Weird issue; not sure what causes it but i got spawn working. Thanks